# Maven system property priority

Tags: java, maven-2, teamcity, system-properties

I have following pom.xml

```
<project>
  <properties>
    <buildNumber>dev</buildNumber>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${buildNumber}</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

This works fine on development machine. If I run `mvn package` I've got `project-1.1-dev.war` artifact. If I run `mvn package -DbuildNumber=121` I've got `package-1.1-121.war`.

But out CI server (TeamCity) always got `project-1.1-dev.war` despite the fact that `buildNumber` property passed to maven (if I remove default property definition from `pom.xml`, maven builds artifact with correct filename).

It seems that system property resolve priority is somehow depends on platform (maven version is equals on both developer machine and TC - 2.2.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bit strange... Maybe you can't force the parameter given in the command line to have a highest priority than the one defined in the `<properties>` tag.

An idea is to use a profile that define the property `buildNumber`:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev-property</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <buildNumber>dev</buildNumber>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

So by default, `buildNumber` will be equals to `dev` value. Now, in your TeamCity command line, disable this profile with the command `mvn ... -P !dev-property` (the `!` before a profile id indicates that the profile must be disabled).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question lies in another question here on SO: [Maven property overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826128/maven-property-overloading)

In short, you need to pass `-DbuildNumber=121` on the maven command line (on the "3 build step: maven" page), because setting system property "buildNumber" on the "6 properties and variables" page does not override the maven property.

Answer (score -1):

Are you familiar with the concept of [SNAPSHOT](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html#pom-relationships-sect-snapshot-versions) versions?  Sounds like what you are trying to do, and is supported out of the box by Maven.  Looks like you want to build *major-minor-incremental* or *major-minor-**dev***, if you can live with *major-minor-incremental-**SNAPSHOT*** instead it should do what you want.

Comment: Not exactly. I need a way to distinguish any two build artifacts (when the are deployed in production). Using SNAPSHOT I can't do that. All build artifacts will have name `project-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war`

Comment: If you have two separate versions you are going to deploy to production they should have different version numbers, the act of creating a release should consume a version.  *SNAPSHOT* builds (or dev builds) should never be deployed.  Are you saying that your build is different depending on which machine it was built on?

Comment: We have incremental development cycle, and change version in the POM descriptor after each change to source code is overkill for us. So we are using following scheme: developer define version of the artifact (based on change semantic: backward compatibility etc) and CI server use incrementing counter for marking artifacts. "dev" artifacts are not deployed to production.

Comment: When you say overkill, do you mean that you don't want TeamCity to commit to version control when it does an incremental build?  How does it manage its `buildNumber`?  I think you could have TeamCity consume incremental builds and your developers continue to set major/minor revisions as they currently do.  I can't see anything in the cycle you've described which breaks the separation provided by *SNAPSHOT*