# How to tell maven to get MAVEN_OPTS from specific file?

Tags: maven

`mvn` command, among others, have following options:

- `-f,--file <arg>`  Force the use of an alternate POM file. (This is for pointing file instead of default `pom.xml` file.)
- `-gs,--global-settings <arg>` Alternate path for the global settings file. (This one is for pointing the `settings.xml` file, which is by default in `.m2` directory.)

Still there is yet one config file uncovered by these options -  `.mavenrc`

So, my question is - Is there a way to tell maven from which file it should get `MAVEN_OPTS`?

Comment: It looks that nothing changed still: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826128/maven-property-overloading

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk - it would be sad if it is true, but still tolerable ) let's wait a bit.

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk that's not related to this issue. The question you're referring to is converting java system properties to maven build properties. That's a different story.

Comment: @greyfairer, it's a pity we can not just write something like <javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword>blablabla</javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword> in pom.xml, just like we can do it with "regular" properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MAVEN_OPTS is a environment variable from the OS. You can set it anyway you want before launching maven.

In bash (linux):

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=...
```

On windows:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=...
```

I think you could even edit the 'mvn' of 'mvn.bat' shell script to get different variables.

Comment: sure, I worth to mention this, than you. Exporting this variable directly is slightly less convenient. Almost indistinguishably, but lest convenient.

Comment: let consider this an answer, since, helas, nothing more relevant can be expected.

Answer (score 6):

Starting with Maven 3.3.1, you can put these settings into the `.mvn/maven.config` file in your project repository.

References:

- [JVM and Command Line Options](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html#JVM_and_Command_Line_Options)
- [MNG-5767](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5767)