# How do I pass -Xlint:deprecation or -Xlint:unchecked to Maven?

Tags: java, maven

When I build my project I get errors like:

```
[INFO] SomeClass.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[INFO] SomeClass.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] SomeClass.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] SomeClass.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

But when I put `-Xlint:deprecation` or `-Xlint:unchecked` in my `MAVEN_OPTS` or `.mvn/maven.config` I get:

```
$ MAVEN_OPTS="-Xlint:unchecked " mvn -B clean test 
Unrecognized option: -Xlint:unchecked
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

What gives?

Answer (score 10):

`-Xlint` is a compiler option, not a maven option or jvm option.

On the command line maven accepts `-Xlint` but it treats it as the `-X` maven option ("debug") and ignores the rest. So it doesn't have the expected effect.

In the specific case of these two compiler options you can set Maven properties that result in the desired compiler options being set. Put these in your project's [`.mvn/maven.config`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11568135/398670), `MAVEN_OPTS` env var, or on the command line:

```
-Dmaven.compiler.showWarnings=true
-Dmaven.compiler.showDeprecation=true
```

See [maven compiler plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html).

You can also use the `compilerArgs` property in your `pom.xml` or a Maven `settings.xml` user-defined profile. I don't see a way to set that List valued property as a system property. You can't use `compilerArgument` or `compilerArguments` either, they [don't have user properties](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#Parameter_Details).

You may also find it useful to control the compiler's logging level; for example, you can silence these warnings with:

```
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo=warn
```

Note that explicitly setting `-Dmaven.compiler.showWarnings=false` will *not* suppress the `-Xlint` messages. See [How can I suppress javac warnings about deprecated api?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1554538/398670) . Maven doesn't appear to offer a way to set the relevant properties `-Xlint:-deprecated -Xlint:-unchecked` on the command line. You can't set them directly  `settings.xml` either because you can't set individual plugin properties. It has to be the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 3):

In my program, I added `-Dmaven.compiler.showWarnings=true -Dmaven.compiler.showDeprecation=true` and Maven still told me `Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details`.

I am using Maven 3.9.0 and jdk 11.

I solved adding required arguments in `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```